# How to change led light fixture back to regular light fixture

Tags: light-fixture, led, installation

I currently have this LED light fixture.

I want to change it back to regular light fixture. Power is off.
[image]

Comment: Sorry for 3 pictures

Comment: *Why* do you want to replace it? Is it broken? Not suitable (too bluish or yellowish of a light, or simply not enough or too much light)? Not compatible with something else (like you want to use "smart" light bulbs, or a dimmer that doesn't work with that specific light)?

Comment: Make sure power is off and get a new fixture.  Undo centre stud and fixture should come off.  Take pictures of how wires are connected and new fixture should be the same.

Comment: @crip659 The problem is there is no regular wires come out.

Comment: whe you take the fixture off you'll find the junction box there will be regular wire in there.

Comment: If you have absolutely no idea how to do this then I can't help you because I like to sleep at night knowing I didn't give just enough information to be dangerous. Monkey see monkey do. If you've never seen it, don't do it.

Answer (score 1):

This fixture is built from the ground up to be LED-only.

Those little yellow dots are the LED *emitters* themselves.  Those components are so reliable that they will outlive all of us.  As such, modern LED fixtures do not make them replaceable - there's no point.  (other parts of the fixture fail, like the electronic power supply on the other end of those black and white wires... they oughta put sockets on those! LOL!)

It's pretty weird.... a light emitter that never burns out, that's a first!   But it's true.

Anyway, there is no socket or any other way to replace "bulbs". The only option is to replace the whole fixture.

First and always - turn off the power in the entire house. It's not worth fooling around trying to identify individual breakers; that might not even work and zap you anyway.

See the rectangles on either side of the stalk.  Those have a slot that looks like a keyhole.  You loosen the Philips screws (visible in the slot) about 5 turns (no need to remove it).  Enough to slide the fixture so the screw lines up with the round part.  Then the screw will drop right through and the fixture drops down.

At that point, take photos of how it was wired.  Generally the fiture only needs 2 wires (besides ground) and the new fixture will attach to those same 2 wires.  But there will be lots of other wires passing through which have other jobs.  Leave those alone.

One other thing. From the markings on this fixture (or the notable lack of any markings from a recognized testing laboratory), it is "cheap Chinese" and was bought mail-order.  These fixtures are not safe and are not legal to attach to AC power, and was sold to you by someone beyond the reach of our laws. Never buy electrical equipment mail-order. Make sure to buy fixtures from reputable, bricks-and-mortar retail shop (or *their* mail order service is fine). Those shops are inspected and sell items which conform to national safety standards.  Because the government can fine or jail them if they do not!

Comment: 2 _VERY_ important steps missing from this. 1) Find the breaker that controls this light and turn it off. 2) once the fixture is removed from the screw slots, grab your phone & take pictures of how the wires are connected to the _back_ of the fixture. _Then and only then_, commence to removing the fixture from the ceiling and installing a new one.

Comment: @FreeMan okay...

Comment: eh, sorry. I've gotten to be in an overly nanny state of mind recently - assuming people are completely incompetent. Guess I should back that down a notch or two, eh?

Comment: @FreeMan lol we all  have days like that... anyway I agreed, added 2 paras.